# SQL ordering by rating/votes

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL statement;

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE votes > 4 ORDER BY (rating/votes) DESC
```

But instead of it only showing WHERE votes > 4, i'd like it to display all the records but giving the priority to ones with votes over 4, still maintaining the rating/votes score

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove `where` clause. Where clause is used to filter records

Comment: Which dbms? (I.e. can vendor specific SQLbe used, or just plain ANSI SQL.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're going for, but I would probably have two parts to the `ORDER BY` clause:

- Prefer ones with over four
- Sort those

That would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
ORDER BY IIF(Votes > 4, 0, 1),
         (rating/votes) DESC
```

Essentially, I assign a number for whether there are more than four votes (0), and one for if there are fewer (1). Since 0 is less than 1, the ones with more than four votes will be pulled first.

You probably don't want a `WHERE` clause for this, because it will filter out any with fewer than four votes.