# Ordering objects by rating accounting for the number or ratings

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to do something similar to the first response in this SO question: [SQL ordering by rating/votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665715/sql-ordering-by-rating-votes), where resources may be rated (one rating per user per resource), but when ordering the resources based on their ratings, any resources with fewer than X separate ratings will appear below those with X or more.

I'm implementing this in Django and I'd very much prefer to avoid the use of raw query and keep within the Django model and query framework.

So far, this is what I have:

```
data = []
data_top = Resource.objects.all().annotate(rating=Avg('resourcerating__rating'),rate_count=Count('resourcerating')).exclude(rate_count__lt=settings.ORB_RESOURCE_MIN_RATINGS).order_by(order_by)
for d in data_top:
    data.append(d)

data_bottom = Resource.objects.all().annotate(rating=Avg('resourcerating__rating'),rate_count=Count('resourcerating')).exclude(rate_count__gte=settings.ORB_RESOURCE_MIN_RATINGS).order_by(order_by)
for d in data_bottom:
    data.append(d)
```

This all functions and returns the ordering by rating as I need, however, it doesn't feel very efficient - what with running 2 queries and looping over the results of each.

Is there a better way I can code this, either in a single query, or at least avoiding looping though each query set?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain

main_query = Resource.objects.all().annotate(rating=Avg('resourcerating__rating'),rate_count=Count('resourcerating'))

data_top_query = main_query.exclude(rate_count__lt=settings.ORB_RESOURCE_MIN_RATINGS).order_by(order_by)
data_bottom_query = main_query.exclude(rate_count__gte=settings.ORB_RESOURCE_MIN_RATINGS).order_by(order_by)

data = list(chain(data_top_query, data_bottom_query))
```

Using itertools.chain is faster than looping each list and appending elements one by one

Also, the querysets will get evaluated when list is called on them (as they don't hit the database till then)

FYI, the above will hit the db twice when evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently querying twice and iterating twice, but you can cut it down to one and one easily-just query for the items ordered by rating, then iterate like this:

```
data_top = []
data_bottom = []
data = Resource.objects.all().annotate(rating=Avg('resourcerating__rating'),rate_count=Count('resourcerating')).order_by(order_by)
for d in data:
    if data.rate_count >= settings.ORB_RESOURCE_MIN_RATINGS:
        data_top.append(d)
    else:
        data_bottom.append(d)

data = data_top + data_bottom
```

This can also be done with the query only, by creating another aggregate column which contains the value `rate_count < settings.ORB_RESOURCE_MIN_RATINGS` (return 0 for values above or at the threshold, 1 for below) and sorting on (new_column, rating). Pretty sure this would require some custom SQL, but perhaps someone else knows otherwise.